# How do I make a bookmark using id and link work as a proper link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, bookmarks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Shanghaiers' TV &amp; Radio - Television</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-tvradio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Goudy+Bookletter+1911" rel="stylesheet">
  <base href="NEED MAIN WEBSITE ADDRESS HERE">
</head>

<body> 
  <h3>Shanghaiers' Television</h3>
  <section>
 <div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="tv/allvideos.html">All Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#concert">Concerts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#nn">Native Nations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#human">Human Trafficking</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sacred">Sacred Lands</a></li>
  <li><a href="#story">Story Telling</a></li>
  <li><a href="#bigfoot">Big Foot &amp; Sasquatch</a></li>
  <li><a href="#interview">Interviews</a></li>
  <li><a href="#psa">Public Service Announcements</a></li>
  <li><a href="#shanghai">Shanghai Tunnels</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
  </section>
  
 <h3 id="concert">Concerts</h3>
    <p>en Taiko</p>
    <p>Maiah Wynee</p>
  
    <h3 id="nn">Native Nations</h3>
  <p>Native American Music</p>
  <p>Occupation of Malheur Wildlife Refuge</p>
  <p>NAYA Canoe Family</p>
  <p>Grand Ronde Tribe Disenrollment &amp; Chinook Language</p>
   
    <h3 id="human">Human Trafficking</h3>
       <p>More info here...</p>

    <h3 id="sacred">Sacred Lands</h3>
       <p>More info here...</p>

    <h3 id="story">Story Telling</h3>
       <p>More info here...</p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have created bookmarks on a page to jump from a navigation menu to other spots on the page. This was done using id="name"; with  place in the navigation menu. When testing the code these bookmarks/links don't work. They either do nothing or show an error message that the page cannot be found.

Found something that said placing an extra '#' in the anchor tag would solve the problem. This does nothing. Ex. - .

Any suggestions on how to correct the problem so the bookmarks actually work as links?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove your faulty baseref tag to make it work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Shanghaiers' TV &amp; Radio - Television</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-tvradio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Goudy+Bookletter+1911" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Shanghaiers' Television</h3>
  <section>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tv/allvideos.html">All Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#concert">Concerts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nn">Native Nations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#human">Human Trafficking</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sacred">Sacred Lands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#story">Story Telling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bigfoot">Big Foot &amp; Sasquatch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#interview">Interviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#psa">Public Service Announcements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#shanghai">Shanghai Tunnels</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

    <h3 id="concert">Concerts</h3>
    <p>en Taiko</p>
    <p>Maiah Wynee</p>

    <h3 id="nn">Native Nations</h3>
    <p>Native American Music</p>
    <p>Occupation of Malheur Wildlife Refuge</p>
    <p>NAYA Canoe Family</p>
    <p>Grand Ronde Tribe Disenrollment &amp; Chinook Language</p>

    <h3 id="human">Human Trafficking</h3>
    <p>More info here...</p>

    <h3 id="sacred">Sacred Lands</h3>
    <p>More info here...</p>

    <h3 id="story">Story Telling</h3>
    <p>More info here...</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Pls use the snippet editor for future posts, it makes life so much easier for all of us.